# How to organize and distribute a Python Application with C extensions?

Tags: python, packaging, project-organization, python-c-extension

I'm working on a Python application that is distributed as source (zipped) and via py2exe (majority).

Now I want to speed up some modules by replacing them with C extensions. Which works quite well for the development part. But the distribution and organization gives me a headache...

My current structure looks like this:

```
.
|-- py_submodule_a/
|-- py_submodule_b/
|   |-- c_extension_ba/
|-- c_extension_x/
|-- setup.py
|-- main.py
```

My question is, where should I place the setup calls/files for my C extensions? I want to make sure that I can always run my application via `main.py` (so I'd rather not wait until distribution to compile the C extensions) but I also want to make sure that the distribution always has the latest C extensions.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to optimize out hot-loops with C-code snippets you could always try something like [scipy.weave](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html).  It is extremely convenient to have the C-code nicely wrapped up in the python package that calls it, and to be able to perform efficient C operations on memory in place.

Comment: Thank you very much! Even though not quite what I was hoping for but it definitely solves my problem!

Comment: The link to `scipy.weave` answer is dead. SciPy moved this to a standalone package + repo in 2017 see e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.11.0/release/1.0.0-notes.html#some-history-and-perspectives   The new pypa project exists here https://pypi.org/project/scipy-weave/ and the github repo is here https://github.com/scipy/weave also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424435/alternative-for-weave-in-python-3